# Ajax Control Toolkit not working on IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using Ajax Control Toolkit version 40412 in my asp.net 4.0 website. When I run the page in Firefox it is working good but I run the page in IE8 it is not rendering toolkit controls and putting "//" characters on the bottom of page.This is happening with every control of toolkit. What can be the problem with this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are using the ToolScriptManager and not the Scriptmanager?

Comment: thank-you I've spent hours searching for a reason why my ajax toolkit controls weren't working at all, no error messages, nothing. It's because I was using the scriptmanager and not the ToolkitScriptManager. THanks!

Comment: I know how much nerves that can cost. Makes me happy that I could help ;)